# Angularjs custom directive two way binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create custom directive and using two way binding (=)

But I want to watch changes in controller when model is changed in directive.

```
<div ng-app="zippyModule">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
    Title: <input ng-model="title">
    <hr>
    <div class="zippy" zippy-title="title" ff="titleChanged()"></div>
  </div>
</div>


function Ctrl3($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    $scope.titleChanged = function() {
        //ALERT COMMING WITH OLD VALUE NOT UPDATED
         alert($scope.title);
    }
}

angular.module('zippyModule', [])
  .directive('zippy', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      replace: true,
        scope: { title:'=zippyTitle',f:'&ff' },
      template: '<input type="text" value="{{title}}"style="width: 90%" ng-click="onclick()"/>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Your controller
          scope.onclick = function() {
               scope.title +="_";
              if (scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
                    scope.$apply();
              }
              scope.f();

          }
      }
    }
  });
```

titleChanged method is calling but $scope.title is comming with old value.
if I remove

```
if (scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
```

this if and call direcly scope.$apply() method,

Apply in progress exception is throwing.

Comment: I know it's gonna sound weird, but put `title` inside another class, and refer to it as `myClass.title`, see if that works :)

Comment: I mean only change `zippy-title="myClass.title"` and the definition in the controller: `$scope.myClass.title`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Omri said above, you should put your model values inside an object on your scope instead of having strings directly on the scope.

However, you probably want to just use ng-model to handle tracking model changes:

```
  angular.module('zippyModule', [])
      .controller('Ctrl3', function($scope) {
      $scope.model = {title : 'Lorem Ipsum'};
        $scope.titleChanged = function() {
            //ALERT COMMING WITH OLD VALUE NOT UPDATED
             alert($scope.model.title);
        }
      })
      .directive('zippy', function(){
        return {
          restrict: 'C',
          replace: true,
            scope: {f:'&ff' },
            require: 'ngModel',
          template: '<input type="text" style="width: 90%" ng-click="onclick()"/>',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // Use ngModelController
              ctrl.$render = function() {
                element.val(ctrl.$modelValue);
              };
              scope.onclick = function() {
                var newVal = ctrl.$modelValue + '_';
                element.val(newVal);
                ctrl.$setViewValue(newVal);
                scope.f();
              }
          }
        }
      });
```

Then update your HTML to use ng-model:

```
    <div ng-app="zippyModule">
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
        Title: <input ng-model="model.title">
        <hr>
        <div class="zippy" zippy-title ng-model="model.title" ff="titleChanged()">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLx9do3c/

Check out the docs for ngModelController for all the other features that you probably will eventually need. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController